# How to convert text document to named entity by gate API in eclipse

Tags: java, log4j

I am using GATE.ac.uk. scr code in eclipse LUNA java 1.8. I have a problem with execution to start the GATE application.it shows the error like this:

"Error during initialisation : gatel:util.GateRuntimeException:Could not infer installed plug-ins home! please set it manually using the -Dgate.plugins.home option in your start-up script. Do you still want to start GATE?"

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (gate.Gate).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

And the main problem is i am not liable to use gate developer GUI. all I should use is GATE jar_files only.
plugins are not getting detected.I already included log4j 1.2.17.jar to eclipse but still i am getting the same log4j errors.
if anybody knows please tell me the way to correct???

https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/src/sheffield/examples/StandAloneAnnie.java
https://gate.ac.uk/gate/src/main/gate/Gate.java
https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch7.html